# Delete empty object from yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file with multiple objects including some empty ones. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password1234"

---

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password5678"

---

---
```

I want to delete the empty objects in the file using ruamel yaml so the file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password1234"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password5678"
```

I tried the code below it doesn't work.

```
for y in yaml_objects:
    if y == None:
        yaml_objects.remove(y)
```

But it generates the file like below:

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password1234"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password5678"

--- null
...
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried printing one of the empty objects? is it None, or a dict of len 0, or something else? Also, any check for `None` should use `is` not `==`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429911/do-the-commands-x-is-none-and-x-none-return-always-the-same-result-if-x-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a YAML file with multiple objects, you have a file with multiple YAML documents.
The way to load such a file is using `load_all()` which returns a generator, returning
the data  structure for each document in turn.

You can turn the output of that generator into a list, which you probably did creating
your `yaml_objects` (but your code is incomplete, so you might be doing something else).
But then iterating over the elements of that list and removing items from that same list, while iterating,
leads to problems. In your case that happens as well and the second to last document (because it shifted in the list from which you are removing) is not removed and is dumped as `--- null\n...`. In such instances, where I have to delete potentially multiple elements from a list, I normally gather the indices of the elements
and then remove the elements using these
indices *in reverse order* (for hopefully obvious reasons).

However, in this case, it is much more easy to discard the empty
documents in the first place, while iterating over the generator:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('input.yaml')
file_out = Path('output.yaml')
    
with ruamel.yaml.YAML(output=file_out) as yaml:
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    for data in yaml.load_all(file_in):
        if data is not None:
            yaml.dump(data)

print(file_out.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password1234"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password5678"
```

If you need to further work on the loaded data, you can also append `data` to a list
but only if it is not `None`:

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

documents = []
for data in yaml.load_all(file_in):
    if data is not None:
        documents.append(data)
for doc in documents:
    doc['apiVersion'] = 'v2'
yaml.dump_all(documents, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: v2
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret1
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password1234"

---

apiVersion: v2
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret2
type: Opaque
data:
  password: "password5678"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Exactly what I was looking for! Follow up question: how do I remove blank lines between two documents. For example if my my file has additional blank lines between the separator `---`, the output also has the additional lines. How do I remove those lines?

Comment: If this post answers your question, please consider accepting it (clicking the V). That way others also know this is a solution, without having to scroll down and read the comments. As for the blank lines, these are preserved in the default (round-trip) mode and attached to the instance `data`, just copy the key/value pairs to a new, empty, dictionary and use that for dumping (if unclear post a new question and tag it `ruamel.yaml`, I will get notified automatically)